# Not getting the correct R2 score for test data

Tags: python, scikit-learn, linear-regression, polynomials

I am supposed to get R2 scores for my train data and test data. Through the following codes, I obtained the right R2 scores for train data, but the R2 score for test data is wrong. Hope someone can help me on this.

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures
from sklearn.metrics.regression import r2_score

np.random.seed(0)
n = 15
x = np.linspace(0,10,n) + np.random.randn(n)/5
y = np.sin(x)+x/6 + np.random.randn(n)/10
x = x.reshape(-1,1)
    
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, random_state = 0)
    
y_train_pred = np.zeros(shape=(10,len(y_train)))
y_test_pred = np.zeros(shape=(10,len(y_test)))
r2_train = np.zeros(shape=(10,))
r2_test = np.zeros(shape=(10,))
        
for i, degree in enumerate([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]):
    poly = PolynomialFeatures(degree=degree)
    X_train_poly = poly.fit_transform(X_train)
    poly.fit(X_train, y_train)
             
    linreg = LinearRegression()
    linreg.fit(X_train_poly, y_train)
       
    y_train_pred[i] = linreg.predict(poly.fit_transform(X_train))
    r2_train[i] = r2_score(y_train, y_train_pred[i])

for j, degree1 in enumerate([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]):
    poly1 = PolynomialFeatures(degree=degree1)
    X_test_poly = poly1.fit_transform(X_test)
    poly1.fit(X_test, y_test)
             
    linreg = LinearRegression()
    linreg.fit(X_test_poly, y_test)
      
    y_test_pred[j] = linreg.predict(poly1.fit_transform(X_test))
    r2_test[j] = r2_score(y_test, y_test_pred[j])
```

I am attaching my current output for reference.[image: Current output]

Comment: You're fitting your linear model to your test data and then scoring based on your test data. You need to fit your model to your training data and then predict with *that* model on your test data.

Comment: Thank you for point out the mistake @CJR, I got it at last! :)